# Icons of deleted files remain until refreshed

Tags: windows-7

In my windows 7 64 bit laptop, every time I delete a file or a folder using the mouse, the icons of the deleted content remain visible (even though the content is actually deleted) until I press F5, which then clears off the icons. Has anyone experienced this behavior on their machines?

My laptop has all win 7 updates installed.

Comment: same problem with me on my desktop

Comment: Have you tried cleaning up unnecessary files using "Disk Clean-up" utility? the issue might be because of large file thumbnail history that gets created overtime.

Comment: I have the same problem with one file that is deleted off the system, but I can't delete the icon off of my desktop. It has been there for months. It tells me that it can't locate the file. Pressing F5 does nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Win 7:

1. Click on your start button and search for index. You should find Indexing Options.
2. Click on Indexing Options.
3. Click The Advanced Button (Admin/elevated privileges needed)
4. Click Rebuild.

{Indexing options can also be found in Control Panel When Large or Small icons instead of Category is selected.}

Comment: The question has nothing to do with indexing.

Comment: The indexing some times breaks which causes refreshing issues i.e. when deleteing, cutting and moving. So rebuild re-structures the indexes and by rebuilding them, hopefully the problem may get solved. It worked for me. i had the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

If Windows is unable to self refresh you may wan to perform a systems file check post a health check.

In CMD
C:>DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
sfc /scannow

Comment: These are the commands for repairing Windows 10. Do you know if they work for Windows 7?

Comment: sfc still works, that hasn’t changed for years. However, not sure about the others, see if DISM is present in Win7. Win10 introduced a different kernel so it may not work.